# Do I have a place for a common wire?

Tags: wiring, boiler

I have a boiler for heat/hot water, with multiple zones.  It is a backup for a ductless mini-split installation.  I'm trying to work something out where the boiler actually does backup the ductless mini-splits automatically, so I'm adding wifi-enabled thermostats where I can.

The boiler control board is a Honeywell Model L7224U.  The manual for that is here:  https://forwardthinking.resideo.com/related_links/thermalsolutions/l7224u/install/69_1720.pdf

I'm trying to do things properly, so if I can, I'd like to use the common in the boiler control board, but I'm not sure if there is one.  I can't find any reference to it in the manual, certainly.  I'm attaching a picture of the control board schematic and the current wiring.

[image: Current Wiring]
[image: Control Board Schematic]

The system wiring is a mess, some dating I think from the 60s, and needs to be cleaned up, so I don't have a complete diagram of that, yet.  And some zones are already using a separate transformer for power, not hooking up to the boiler control board. But, again, if I can do things properly, and use a common from the boiler control, I'd like to do that.

Comment: Can you measure to see if there's 24VAC between terminals 2 and 3 with the boiler running?  Also, is there a zone controller somewhere in the system, or are the zone thermostats simply wired straight to the zone valves?\

Comment: The zone thermostats are wired directly to the zone valves.  I’ll have to check on the voltage of terminals 2 and 3.

Comment: 27 volts between 2 and 3, which is the same as between 1 and 2.

Comment: Do either of terminals 2 or 3 have continuity to ground with the boiler OFF, for that matter?

Comment: As far as I can tell, no.  I don't have a ground wire, so I measured continuity between terminals 2 and 3 and the cable sheath.

Comment: What make and model are your zone valves, and how are they wired?

Comment: Various models of Honeywell.  The most recent one is model V8043E1012.  Would an isolation relay make more sense at this point?

Comment: We'd need to know more about your system to know for sure

Comment: Can you trace out the wiring for at least one of the thermostat/zone valve pairs and post a diagram, or matching photos for that matter?

Comment: Will come back to this.  When I was trying to trace out a diagram, I discovered CAT-5 cable being used in some places instead of thermostat wiring, so . . . I have work to do.